# Nuxt generate and firebase gives timer warning

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, dynamic-links

I'm dynamically generating routes in Nuxt.js based on a collection in firestore. Everything generates fine but then it gives this warning.

```
   ╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                                      │
   │   ⚠ Nuxt Warning                                                                     │
   │                                                                                      │
   │   The command 'nuxt generate' finished but did not exit after 5s                     │
   │   This is most likely not caused by a bug in Nuxt.js                                 │
   │   Make sure to cleanup all timers and listeners you or your plugins/modules start.   │
   │   Nuxt.js will now force exit                                                        │
   │                                                                                      │
   │   DeprecationWarning: Starting with Nuxt version 3 this will be a fatal error        │
   │                                                                                      │
   ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Following advice from [this post](https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/93) I've added the following snippet:

```
export default {
  hooks: {
    generate: {
      done(builder) {
        firebase.firestore.terminate()
      }
    }
  },
}
```

But then that yields a Fatal error:

```
 FATAL  The client has already been terminated.                                                                                       23:39:58  

  at new FirestoreError (node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:1201:28)
  at FirestoreClient.verifyNotTerminated (node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:17311:19)
  at FirestoreClient.listen (node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:17371:14)
  at CollectionReference.Query$1.onSnapshotInternal (node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:21820:48)
  at CollectionReference.Query$1.getViaSnapshotListener (node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:21851:29)
  at node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:21846:23
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at CollectionReference.Query$1.get (node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:21836:16)
  at routes (nuxt.config.js:185:79)
  at promisifyRoute (node_modules\@nuxtjs\sitemap\lib\cache.js:59:17)
  at AsyncCache.load [as _load] (node_modules\@nuxtjs\sitemap\lib\cache.js:18:28)
  at AsyncCache.get (node_modules\async-cache\ac.js:63:8)
  at internal/util.js:297:30
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at AsyncCache.get (internal/util.js:296:12)
  at generateSitemap (node_modules\@nuxtjs\sitemap\lib\generator.js:54:37)


   ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                                                        │
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                                                   │
   │                                                                                        │
   │   FirebaseError: [code=failed-precondition]: The client has already been terminated.   │
   │                                                                                        │
   ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

This is my routes method taken in part from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57501556/nuxt-dynamic-routing-on-firebase):

```
generate: {
    async routes() {
      const collection = await db.collection('restaurants').get();
      return collection .docs.map(x => `/restaurant/${x.title}`);
    }
},
```

This warning only came up when I added the generate object so I know the problem lies in that area. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Firebase init code in `nuxt.config.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  databaseURL: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: ''
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const fireDb = firebase.firestore();

export default {
    generate :{...}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your firebase initialization code?

Comment: @HardikShah done

Comment: firebase initialize code is in `nuxt.config.js` or as `plugin`!!! please try as a plugin. Any initialization with firestore in that code like for connection to the specific store??

Comment: @HardikShah I do have it in a plugin. But if I do ```import {fireDb} from '@/plugins/firebase'``` in ```nuxt.config.js``` I get ```Cannot find module '@/plugins/firebase'``` so I've resorted to the other method for now

Comment: Are you exporting `fireDb` from `plugins/firebase.js`?

Answer (score 1):

If you still need help, you can reach out to Firebase directly as they provides free support here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Answer (score 0):

From `plugins/firebase.js` you should export `fireDb` and you can import in any component and use that variable as below

In `plugins/firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  const config = {
    apiKey: '',
    authDomain: '',
    databaseURL: '',
    projectId: '',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: ''
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

const fireDb = firebase.firestore();

export { fireDb };
```

Comment: firebase.database() or firebase.firestore() ?

Comment: my bad! in my case it was database in yours it's firestore

Comment: This is what I have already. I use ```fireDb``` in the ```.vue``` files in my project so it gets exported correctly. I just can't access it in ```nuxt.config.js``` I don't know why

Comment: Why you require in nuxt.config.js can you explain!??

Comment: So that I can generate dynamic routes. So there's a collection in my database called restaurants and I want each restaurant to have its own route (page). But I don't want to create them manually so I'm using nuxt to generate routes based on that collection.

Comment: In my opinion if you try to access firedb in `nuxt.config.js` than it will give you a warning as you got `The command 'nuxt generate' finished but did not exit after 5s  ` coz at build time only you are trying to access the firestore not at runtime

Answer (score 0):

NEW:

This is an issue with node and the realtimedatabase.

The following works without having to kill the process:
`this.$fire.database.goOffline()`

---

OLD WITH SIDEEFFECTS (DONT USE):

See the following stackoverflow for solutions. I can confirtm that `process.exit()` worked for my usecase.

[node process doesn't exit after firebase once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046639/node-process-doesnt-exit-after-firebase-once)

Comment: Sorry the update caused the database not be injected. As soon as i fixed that, and the database was working the timeout began again.
As soon as a request is being made to the database, the timeout starts again...
Funnily, it says V.6 but it made me do the migration as required by V.7 ... so despite the package json, i think im on `nuxtjs/firebase^7`

Comment: Ah, in this case I'm not using `@nuxtjs/firebase` apologies for not specifying that in the question

Comment: well it doesn't matter because in the end `nuxtjs/firebase` is just a premade plugin. theres no difference.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. `@nuxtjs/firebase` is a plugin that controls `firebase`. Because I didn't use the plugin in the project, I didn't see how an answer that quoted an upgrade of the plugin to be the solution for my use case.

Comment: Nevermind. I updated my answer with a working solution!

Answer (score 0):

For those who still did not manage to fix this, nuxt firebase module has a config flag to terminate thing on generate:

terminateDatabasesAfterGenerate: true

View doc here: https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/guide/options/